# Partial Redirect in React-Router 4.0.0.alpha6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redirect

In react-router **4.0.0.alpha6**, I want to achieve this:

```
site.com/en -> site.com
site.com/en/hi -> site.com/hi
site.com/en/hi/there -> site.com/hi/there
```

How would I go about it? 
I've tried a lot from the docs but can't seem to get it to work sadly...

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Do you want to redirect urls only? or render different components? Could you post what you tried? Maybe that will explain what you want to do a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** While you mention v4 alpha, I am going to use the beta code (unreleased, but available through the v4 branch in the repo).

Essentially what you want to do is to identify any `pathname` that begins with the segment `en`, split it from the rest of the URL segments, and redirect to whatever the rest of the `pathname` is.

As a regular expression, you could match this with `/^\/en(\/.*)?$/`. React Router uses `path-to-regexp` to match pathnames, which does support regular expressions, but React Router does not (at least not directly). Still, you can configure a path that will match this by using unnamed parameters.

```js
<Route path='/en(/*)' component={EnRedirect} />
```

That should match `/en`, `/en`, and `/en/hi`, but not `/english`. Next, in the component, you will need to split the matched `url` into segments, remove the `en`, rejoin the segments, and redirect.

```js
const EnRedirect = ({ match }) => {
  const parts = match.url.split('/')
  parts.splice(1,1)
  const to = parts.join('/')
  return <Redirect to={to} /> 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you tell me the commit number of the version of the #v4 branch you use, as I can't seem to find a commit that will install.

Comment: If you are trying to install using NPM, that will not work yet. You would need to `git clone` React Router, check out the `v4` branch, go to the `packages/react-router` directory (React Router has been converted to multiple packages: `react-router`, `react-router-dom`, and `react-router-native`), `npm link` the package, then go to your project and `npm link react-router`. It is a lot more steps than `npm install react-router@next`, but until the beta is released, that is what you'll need to do to use the beta code in your project.

Comment: Having said that, I think that you could get this to work in the alpha by changing `Route` to `Match`, `path` to `pattern`, and `match.url` to `match.pathname`.

Comment: Paul, thank you so much, I was able to get it to work using those replacements:

`const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Match
        pattern='/en(/*)'
        component={EnRedirect}
      />
      <Match
        pattern='/'
        component={Routes}
      />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)

const EnRedirect = ({ location }) => {
  let parts = location.pathname.split('/')
  parts.splice(1, 1)
  return <Redirect to={parts.join('/')} />
}`